# How to store time duration with PostgreSQL and Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

We want users to register the amount of time they work on something. For example, let's say I've worked *two hours and a half* for a project, then I want to fill a form input with `2:30` --two hours and thirty minutes-- and store it in the database. The same for `1:45` --one hour and forty five minutes-- to bring another case.
Then we will use that information to calculate the amount of money that should be assigned to that activity.

For example, if one hour is 10 USD, then:

- 15 minutes --> $2.5
- 30 minutes --> $5
- 1 hour --> $10
- 2:30 hours --> $25

Should we convert `2:30` to seconds to store it in the database? Or is there a better solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It's better to avoid floating point for discrete values. Since the smallest meaningful value to you is minutes, that's what I would recommend storing the time in. Storing seconds provides unnecessary resolution (more data), and storing hours either gets you into storing decimals or means you don't have enough precision.

How you store the value depends on which version of Rails you're on. If 5.1, there is native support for the [interval column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT) types in Postgres. I would use it if you have it, but if you don't it's not a dealbreaker, just use an integer column.

Comment: One advantage of storing seconds vs minutes is that you can pass the value straight to and from [ActiveSupport::Duration](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html).

Answer (score 2):

What about?

```
Time.parse("0:15").seconds_since_midnight / 3600 * 10 => 2.5
```

Personally I would store number of seconds instead of time type.

Answer (score 0):

with Postgres I would consider ideao of using interval data type, eg:

```
t=# with t(v) as (values('2:30'::text),('2 12:31:00'::text),('38 hours 21 minutes 4 seconds'))
select v, v::interval,justify_interval(v::interval),extract(epoch from v::interval) from t;
               v               |        v        | justify_interval | date_part
-------------------------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------
 2:30                          | 02:30:00        | 02:30:00         |      9000
 2 12:31:00                    | 2 days 12:31:00 | 2 days 12:31:00  |    217860
 38 hours 21 minutes 4 seconds | 38:21:04        | 1 day 14:21:04   |    138064
(3 rows)
```